# method "__construct()" is type-hinted "iterable"

Tags: symfony-4.3

I have 2 files.

services.yaml

```
imports:
    - { resource: services/service_test.yaml }

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
```

and service_test.yaml

```
services:
    _defaults:
      autowire: true
      autoconfigure: true

    App\Test\TestAbstract:
      abstract: true

    App\Test\TestA:
      parent: App\Test\TestAbstract
      autowire: false
      autoconfigure: false
      tags:
        - { name: app.test }

    App\Test\TestManager:
      arguments: [!tagged { tag: 'app.test' }]
```

my class TestManager has a constructor

```
public function __construct(iterable $tests, LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    dump($tests);
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

With that configuration I have the error:

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Test\TestManager": argument "$tests" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "iterable", you should configure its value explicitly.
```

How can I get my tagged services with !tag ?

Comment: If you resolved the issues , can you publish the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

App\Test\TestManager:
arguments: [!tagged { tag: 'app.test' }]

In the arguments i suggest to try adding
!tagged_iterator app.test

Answer (score 1):

If any one is here to find a solution, try to initiate an empty array into the constructor by adding  = [].

Example:

public function __construct(iterable $tests = [], LoggerInterface $logger)